# Can't horizontally center div inside another div

Tags: html, css, center, centering, text-align

generally, I know how to center divs but I am lost for the following case:

```css
/* Container4 Styling */

.container4 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #CDE5E1;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Tab HP Styling */

.one {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}


/* Tab HP BUTTON Styling */

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.button-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

a.button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.active {
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

div[class*="content-"] {
  display: none;
}

div.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container4">


  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-1 active one">
      <h1>Content</h1>



      <div class="button-wrap">
        <a href="#" class="button">  Button1  </a>
        <a href="#" class="button">    Button2  </a>
        <a href="#" class="button">  Button3  </a>
        <a href="#" class="button">  Button4 </a>
      </div>



    </div>

    <div class="content-2 two"> content 2 </div>

    <div class="content-2 three"> content 3 </div>

    <div class="content-2 four"> content 4 </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

So basically, my issue is that I need my buttons to stick to the bottom of 'Container 4' div. For doing that, I positioned the 'button-wrap' to absolute and 'bottom: 0'. But then the 4 buttons are no longer centered. I tried SO many different options (adding margin: 0 auto; text-align; changing positions etc) but none of them worked for me. It's either removing the positioning absolute (which then centers the buttons but also moves the buttons up to the top of the Container 4 div). Or when I use absolute (as shown in the code) then the buttons stick to the bottom but are no longer centered.

And just for context: this is build with Jquery, so that on click on the button the respective content (1, 2, 3 or 4) will be shown in Container4.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: add `width: 100%` to .button-wrap

Comment: @dmikester1 That worked, thanks SO much!! However, I just run into another problem with this code :( The way I have written as shown here, the other buttons don't work anymore. Meaning, if I press them the Container4 div just stays empty instead of loading the new content. It works again when I place the button-wrapper div outside of the content div (both divs are still in the Container 4 div though). BUT then the buttons are no longer in the Container4 div but are at the top of the next section/div. I tried adding inline-block, but that didn't help. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'm guessing you have more code than this here in this question.  Because there is no functionality attached those buttons currently.  There is no way to figure out what is going on without seeing the rest of your code.  But that would probably be best in a whole new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the buttons div take up the whole width so they will center properly.  Add `width: 100%;` to `.button-wrap`.

```css
/* Container4 Styling */

.container4 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #CDE5E1;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Tab HP Styling */

.one {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}


/* Tab HP BUTTON Styling */

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.button-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

a.button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.active {
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

div[class*="content-"] {
  display: none;
}

div.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container4">

  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-1 active one">
      <h1>Content</h1>

      <div class="button-wrap">
        <a href="#" class="button">Button1</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">Button2</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">Button3</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">Button4</a>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="content-2 two"> content 2 </div>

    <div class="content-2 three"> content 3 </div>

    <div class="content-2 four"> content 4 </div>

  </div>

</div>
```